# Google Map not rendering in Angular view after hosting

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, google-maps

I am using Angular.js in my MVC 5 project. There is a Google Map using in my Angular view, please see the Google Map directive in app.js.

```
myApp.directive('googlemap', function ($compile) {
return {
    controller: function ($scope) {
        var map;

        this.registerMap = function (myMap) {
            var center = myMap.getCenter(),
              latitude = center.lat(),
              longitude = center.lng();
            //zoom = center.zoom();

            map = myMap;
            $scope.latitude = latitude;
            $scope.longitude = longitude;
            $scope.zoom = map.getZoom();
        };

        $scope.$watch('latitude + longitude', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                var center = map.getCenter(),
                  latitude = center.lat(),
                  longitude = center.lng();
                if ($scope.latitude !== latitude || $scope.longitude !== longitude)
                    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng($scope.latitude, $scope.longitude));
            }
        });
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        var mapOptions,
          latitude = attrs.latitude,
          longitude = attrs.longitude,
          //controlTemplate,
          //controlElem,
          map;

        // parsing latLong or setting default location
        latitude = latitude && parseFloat(latitude, 10) || 43.074688;
        longitude = longitude && parseFloat(longitude, 10) || -89.384294;

        mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(elem[0], mapOptions);

        //var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        //    position: myCenter,
        //    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        //});

        //marker.setMap(map);

        //$scope.zoom = map.getZoom();

        ctrl.registerMap(map);

        //controlTemplate = document.getElementById('whereControl').innerHTML.trim();
        //controlElem = $compile(controlTemplate)(scope);
        //map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(controlElem[0]);

        function centerChangedCallback(scope, map) {
            return function () {
                var center = map.getCenter();
                scope.latitude = center.lat();
                scope.longitude = center.lng();
                scope.zoom = map.getZoom();
                if (!scope.$$phase) scope.$apply();
            };
        }
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', centerChangedCallback(scope, map));
    }
};});
```

I use this `directive` in my html

```
<div class="col-sm-10" style="height:200px;" googlemap latitude="43.074688" longitude="-89.384294"></div>
```

It works fine in local host. After host this page in web server, map not rendering correctly and it shows error:

[image]

I have already Google Map API key and there is no Referrers in Developer

console

[image]

**Edit:**

**controller**

```
function RouterCtrl($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

var _RouterId = $routeParams.routerid;

$scope.models = {
    LocationName: $scope.LocationName,
    RouterID: $scope.RouterID,
}

$scope.SaveRouter = function () {

    var Router = {
        Id: 0,
        Location: $scope.LocationName,
        Latitude: $scope.latitude,
        Longitude: $scope.longitude,
        SerialNumber: $scope.RouterID,
    }

    $http.post("Router/Create", { model: Router }).success(function (data) {
        alert('success');
    });

}

// End 

// Router List link

$scope.RoutersList = function () {
    window.location.href = '#/listrouter';
}}RouterCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams'];
```

I am missing controller declaration in `app.js`.

```
DotWiFi.controller('RouterCtrl', RouterCtrl);
```

This is the refer script for Google Map.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaS*************************">    </script>
```

Comment: This is a dependency error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr. Please show your controller.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. Your are right sir, I am missing this line in app.js 'myApp.controller('RouterCtrl', RouterCtrl);' No the error is solved. But the map is still disappear.

Comment: Get a server application key and replace this browser application key with that.

Comment: I check the view source in local and sever. is there any problem after the script minification ? Because in local webpage source shows more script reference but the hosted webpage shows mininal script. :(

Comment: You can find out by catching the error. Here's a useful article: https://rollbar.com/blog/post/2013/07/25/debug-production-errors-in-minified-javascript-with-source-maps-and-rollbar. Also, in the case you need further help with it, please post html header as well.

Comment: I realize this is for rollbar, but you will get the gist on how to do error handling for min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. There is a script reference error occurred after hosting. `app.js` is not included in the `_Layout.cshtml`, that's the reason to show this error. I add the script reference directly without using Bundle. Now it's solved.